# Arquivos não aparecem após apagar gitignore

Tags: git, github, sourcetree

Eu criei uma repositório localmente, porém antes de subir os arquivos no repositório do servidor eu utilizei o sourcetree para ignorar arquivos que eu não precisava subir e logo ele criou um .gitignore, porém eu apaguei esse arquivo e agora os arquivos ignorados antes ainda estão ignorados mesmo sem o arquivo .gitignore.

já recriei apaguei o repositório criei de novo, refiz toda a pasta e nada.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que você precisa dar commit na mudança que você fez (excluir o arquivo .gitignore) e depois adicionar manualmente os arquivos que estavam no gitignore.

Creio que se você executar o comando `git add .` deve funcionar. Se não funcionar tente `git add <pasta que estava no gitignore >`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tentei e não resolveu, o gitignore subiu mas em branco e mesmo assim ele não sobe o que ignorei antes, quando eu dou o comando add ele aparece a mensagem dos arquivos que estão sendo ignorados mas no arquivo do gitignore novo não tem nada.

Comment: Tenta git add -f <arquivos>. Esse paramento -f (ou —force) adiciona os arquivos mesmo que ainda estejam no gitignore.

Comment: Achei o problema e resolvi de acordo com esse artigo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907829/sourcetree-adding-files-in-global-gitignore-not-in-repository-gitignore

Quando colocamos para ignorar um arquivo no SourceTree como global ele criar um .gitignore dele pra ignorar arquivos globalmente, nas configurações do git no próprio programa eu removi o que estava ignorando e funcionou.